# View as first responder

Tags: iphone

Hi all i want to know how to make subView added to content view of cell to become firstResponder.When i touch cell tableViewDidSelectRow methods get called.I have added customView as subView to cell.I have implemented delegate method which gets called when toches in custom view gets ended.But this method gets called after tableViewDidSelectRow  method is called.I want first the delegate method to get called and then tableViewDidSelectRow .I have even set customView excluiveTouch property to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely ,

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

will called after DidSelectRowFor . Because didSelect called as we click the cell and touchesEnded  after when we removing the finger.

if u want touchesEnded must called before DidSelectRowFor than you have to override the some method. like

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder in cell class as well as in custom class properly. also override
- (UIResponder *)nextResponder this method to call next responder.

try once this . and let me know whether working or not?